# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined

Tags: jquery, primefaces

Estou com um problema quando clico em um botão que é um botão de aprovar, toda vez que eu clico no botão dá esse erro do título da pergunta, esse erro só acontece porque tenho essas duas grid abaixo no código, se eu tirar uma ele não dá mais esse erro não sei o que pode estar acontecendo, alguém tem uma luz? já verifiquei se poder ser id's iguais ou outras coisas não encontrei nada o que pode ser.

```
<div id="tabsCandidatos">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabCandidatosInternos">Candidatos Internos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabCandidatosExternos">Candidatos Externos</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div>

        <div id="tabCandidatosInternos">

            <br/><br/><br/>

            <div>

                <h:form id="formCandidatoInterno">
                   <p:growl id="msgsCandidatoInterno" showDetail="true"/>

                   <p:dataTable id="dataTableCandidatoInterno" 
                                widgetVar="listaCandidatoInterno" 
                                var="candidatoInterno" 
                                value="#{candidatoInternoView.listaCandidatoInterno}" 
                                editable="true" 
                                style="margin-bottom:20px"
                                resizableColumns="true" 
                                liveResize="false">

                       <f:facet name="header">
                           Funcionários
                       </f:facet>

                       <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{candidatoInternoView.onRowEdit}" update=":formCandidatoInterno:msgsCandidatoInterno, listaCandidatoInterno"/>
                       <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{candidatoInternoView.onRowCancel}" update=":formCandidatoInterno:msgsCandidatoInterno, listaCandidatoInterno"/>

                       <p:column headerText="Matricula" style="width:150px">
                           <p:cellEditor>
                               <f:facet name="output">
                                   <p:autoComplete minQueryLength="3" value="#{candidatoInterno.matricula}" completeMethod="#{candidatoInternoView.pesquisaPorNomeFuncionario}" effect="fade" update=":formCandidatoInterno:msgsCandidatoInterno" style="width:100px">
                                      <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{candidatoInternoView.selectRowCandidatoInterno(candidatoInterno)}" update=":formCandidatoInterno:dataTableCandidatoInterno, :formCandidatoInterno:msgsCandidatoInterno, listaCandidatoInterno"/>
                                   </p:autoComplete>
                               </f:facet>
                               <f:facet name="input">
                                   <p:autoComplete minQueryLength="3" value="#{candidatoInterno.matricula}" completeMethod="#{candidatoInternoView.pesquisaPorNomeFuncionario}" effect="fade" update=":formCandidatoInterno:msgsCandidatoInterno">
                                      <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{candidatoInternoView.selectRowCandidatoInterno(candidatoInterno)}" update=":formCandidatoInterno:dataTableCandidatoInterno, :formCandidatoInterno:msgsCandidatoInterno, listaCandidatoInterno"/>
                                   </p:autoComplete>
                               </f:facet>
                           </p:cellEditor>
                       </p:column>

                       <p:column headerText="Data de Admissão">
                           <p:cellEditor>
                               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{candidatoInterno.dataAdmissao}" /></f:facet>
                               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{candidatoInterno.dataAdmissao}" style="width:100%" label="Data de Admissão" disabled="true"/></f:facet>
                           </p:cellEditor>
                       </p:column>

                       <p:column headerText="Empresa">
                           <p:cellEditor>
                               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{candidatoInterno.nomeEmpresa}" /></f:facet>
                               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{candidatoInterno.nomeEmpresa}" style="width:100%" label="Empresa" disabled="true"/></f:facet>
                           </p:cellEditor>
                       </p:column>

                       <p:column headerText="Centro de Custo">
                           <p:cellEditor>
                               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{candidatoInterno.nomeCentroCusto}" /></f:facet>
                               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{candidatoInterno.nomeCentroCusto}" style="width:100%" label="Centro de Custo" disabled="true"/></f:facet>
                           </p:cellEditor>
                       </p:column>

                       <p:column headerText="Cargo">
                           <p:cellEditor>
                               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{candidatoInterno.nomeCargo}" /></f:facet>
                               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{candidatoInterno.nomeCargo}" style="width:100%" label="Cargo" disabled="true"/></f:facet>
                           </p:cellEditor>
                       </p:column>

                       <p:column headerText="Tipo">
                           <p:cellEditor>
                               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{candidatoInterno.nomeTipo}" /></f:facet>
                               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{candidatoInterno.nomeTipo}" style="width:100%" label="Tipo" disabled="true"/></f:facet>
                           </p:cellEditor>
                       </p:column>

                       <p:column headerText="Salário">
                           <p:cellEditor>
                               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{candidatoInterno.salario}" /></f:facet>
                               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{candidatoInterno.salario}" style="width:100%" label="Salário" disabled="true"/></f:facet>
                           </p:cellEditor>
                       </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Data Prevista">
                           <p:cellEditor>
                               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{candidatoInterno.dataPrevista}" /></f:facet>
                               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{candidatoInterno.dataPrevista}" style="width:100%" label="Data Prevista"/></f:facet>
                           </p:cellEditor>
                       </p:column>

                       <p:column headerText="Gerar Substituição">
                            <p:cellEditor>
                               <f:facet name="output">
                                    <p:commandButton value="Gerar" styleClass="ui-priority-primary"/>
                                </f:facet>
                               <f:facet name="input">
                                    <p:commandButton value="Gerar" styleClass="ui-priority-primary"/>
                                </f:facet>
                            </p:cellEditor>
                       </p:column>

                       <p:column style="width:32px">
                           <p:rowEditor />
                       </p:column>
                   </p:dataTable>

                    <div class="ui-g">
                        <div class="ui-g-12">
                            <p:commandButton value="Novo Registro" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" process="@this" update=":formCandidatoInterno:msgsCandidatoInterno, listaCandidatoInterno"
                                             actionListener="#{candidatoInternoView.onAddNew()}" oncomplete="PF('listaCandidatoInterno').addRow();"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </h:form>

                <p:inputText id="listaCandidatoInterno" name="listaCandidatoInterno" value="#{candidatoInternoView.listaCandidatoInternoToJSON}" type="hidden">
                    <p:ajax/>
                </p:inputText>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="tabCandidatosExternos">

            <br/><br/><br/>

            <div>
                <h:form id="formCandidatoExterno">
                   <p:growl id="msgsCandidatoExterno" showDetail="true"/>

                   <p:dataTable id="dataTableCandidatoExterno" 
                                widgetVar="listaCandidatoExterno" 
                                var="candidatoExterno" 
                                value="#{candidatoExternoView.listaCandidatoExterno}" 
                                editable="true" 
                                style="margin-bottom:20px"
                                resizableColumns="true" 
                                liveResize="false">

                       <f:facet name="header">
                           Funcionários
                       </f:facet>

                       <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{candidatoExternoView.onRowEdit}" update=":formCandidatoExterno:msgsCandidatoExterno, listaCandidatoExterno"/>
                       <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{candidatoExternoView.onRowCancel}" update=":formCandidatoExterno:msgsCandidatoExterno, listaCandidatoExterno"/>

                       <p:column headerText="Nome">
                           <p:cellEditor>
                               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{candidatoExterno.nomePessoa}" /></f:facet>
                               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{candidatoExterno.nomePessoa}" style="width:100%" label="Nome"/></f:facet>
                           </p:cellEditor>
                       </p:column>

                       <p:column headerText="Email">
                           <p:cellEditor>
                               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{candidatoExterno.email}" /></f:facet>
                               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{candidatoExterno.email}" style="width:100%" label="Email"/></f:facet>
                           </p:cellEditor>
                       </p:column>

                       <p:column headerText="Telefone">
                           <p:cellEditor>
                               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{candidatoExterno.telefone}" /></f:facet>
                               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{candidatoExterno.telefone}" style="width:100%" label="Telefone"/></f:facet>
                           </p:cellEditor>
                       </p:column>

                       <p:column style="width:32px">
                           <p:rowEditor />
                       </p:column>
                   </p:dataTable>

                    <div class="ui-g">
                        <div class="ui-g-12">
                            <p:commandButton value="Novo Registro" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" process="@this" update=":formCandidatoExterno:msgsCandidatoExterno, listaCandidatoExterno"
                                             actionListener="#{candidatoExternoView.onAddNew()}" oncomplete="PF('listaCandidatoExterno').addRow();"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </h:form>

                <p:inputText id="listaCandidatoExterno" name="listaCandidatoExterno" value="#{candidatoExternoView.listaCandidatoExternoToJSON}" type="hidden">
                    <p:ajax/>
                </p:inputText>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```